# Font size in TextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview, font-size

I just plunked a textview down on a view, and found that the attributes inspector in IB doesn't seem to allow changing font size.  Is that possible, or am I stuck with the default size?

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have the textview selected in Interface Builder, go to the Font menu and select Show Fonts. You can pick the font and size there.